# how to stop running function when calling another in js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to apply text animations to a text by adding classes (btn1, btn2, btn3...) using the `onclick` function, but when I click the buttons all related functions get applied to the text. I want to stop running function while calling another. I need only one function active at a time. How can i achieve that?

```js
function oneAnim() {
   var my_static_element = document.querySelector(".naming");
   my_static_element.classList.add("btn1");
}

function twoAnim() {
   var my_static_element = document.querySelector(".naming");
   my_static_element.classList.add("btn2");

}
function threeAnim() {
   var my_static_element = document.querySelector(".naming");
   my_static_element.classList.add("btn3");
}
function fourAnim() {
   var my_static_element = document.querySelector(".naming");
   my_static_element.classList.add("btn4");
}
```

```css
.display_box .btn1{
    animation: eightanim 5s ease-in-out;
    
     } 

     @keyframes eightanim{
        0%{
           
        }
        30%{
            transform: rotate3d(.1, .2, 1, 8turn);
        }
        100%{
            transform: rotate3d(.1, .2, 1, 8turn);
        }
    }


.display_box .btn2{
    animation: nineanim 5s ease-in-out;
    
     } 

     @keyframes nineanim{
        0%{
           
        }
        30%{
            transform: rotate3d(.1, 2, .01 , 8turn);
        }
        100%{
            transform: rotate3d(.1, 2, .01,  8turn);
        }
    }


.display_box .btn3{
    animation: tenanim 5s ease-in-out;
    
     } 

     @keyframes tenanim{
        0%{
           
        }
        30%{
            transform: rotateX(-180deg);
            transform-origin: 50% 50% -230px;
           
        }
        50%{
            transform: rotateX(180deg);
           
        }
        70%{
            transform: rotateX(60deg);
            transform-origin: 50% 50% 230px;
        }
        80%{
            transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 50% -230px;
        }

        
    }

    
   .display_box .btn4{
    animation: elevenanim 3s ease-in-out;
    
     } 

     @keyframes elevenanim{
        0%{
           
        }
        10%{
          transform-origin: 50% 50% 300px;
        }
        30%{
            transform: rotateX(-180deg) scale3d(.2, .1, .6);
    transform-origin: 50% 50% 300px;
           
        }
        50%{
            transform: rotateX(46deg) ;
            transform-origin: 50% 50% 50px;
        }
        
        100%{
            transform: rotateX(0deg) ;
            transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
            
        }

        
    }
     

    

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<button class="btn btn1" onclick="oneAnim()" >animation1</button>
<button class="btn btn2" onclick="twoAnim()">animation2</button>
<button class="btn btn3" onclick="threeAnim()">animation3</button>
<button class="btn btn4" onclick="tenAnim()">animation4</button>
 
<div class="display_box">
  <div class="naming"><span>Hello World</span></div>
</div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

sorry for not explaining my question properly. naimations are not properly displaying here.. but you can see functons get applies only once. then get error.

Comment: Please include the relevant JavaScript and CSS in the runnable code snippet.  Additionally, there is a typo in the HTML which, while unlikely to cause problems, should be corrected just in case.  It's always best to start with structurally valid code.

Comment: If an element is animated due to it belonging to a particular css class, you could use javascript to remove that class from the element in the code that starts a different animation. Have a different animation per class, and apply only one class to the element at a given time.

Comment: done.. sorry animations are not proper here.. but function get applied only once, dont know why.

Comment: when i add class to the element with js function.. can i remove all existing classes that added before?

Comment: @itishri Yes you can remove all css classes. `yourElement.class=''` should clean this attribute.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).